# I am having all the time this issue after running my app

Tags: objective-c, ios

I don't know why, but after a while working without problems I added some buttons, then I launched my app and this error appeared:

> ld: duplicate symbol _x in
>   /Users/alexbarco/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RecolectaDatos-ayjpqqcajbhuzvbkvernzsyunpbe/Build/Intermediates/RecolectaDatos.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RecolectaDatos.build/Objects-normal/i386/SeconViewController.o
>   and
>   /Users/alexbarco/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RecolectaDatos-ayjpqqcajbhuzvbkvernzsyunpbe/Build/Intermediates/RecolectaDatos.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RecolectaDatos.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
>   for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I have duplicate symbol errors, it is almost always because I have a circular #import in my headers. The solution is quite simple, use forward declarations where possible, and #import .h files from .m files instead.

There are just two cases where you need to #import one .h from another:

1. if you are extending the class in the #import
2. you are *implementing* a protocol in the #import

Specifically, you *do not* need to import files just to use a class name or protocol in your signatures; instead use forward declarations.

For example, this (in Bar.h):

```
#import "Foo.h"
```

might become this (Bar.h):

```
@class Foo;
@protocol FooDelegate;
```

and bar.m:

```
#import "Foo.h"
```

Here is a link to [the documentation on forward declarations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-87895).

Comment: what do you mean with "use forward declarations"?

Comment: As demonstrated in my answer, Objective-C allows you to tell the compiler that a class or protocol "will exist at runtime", or basically, "don't complain that you can't find this class". The syntax is quite simple, just use `@class Foo;` to tell the compiler "trust me, there *is* such a type as Foo, and it is a class", and `@protocol FooDelegate;' says "Trust me, there is a protocol called "FooDelegate". These allow you to use those identifiers in your method signatures and @property declarations *without* needing to #import the files they actually live in.

Comment: I still have the problem...                                                  linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: is the same bit in there about `duplicate symbol _x`?

Comment: And, did you thoroughly remove #import declarations from  all corners of your app (wherever possible)?

Comment: This only applies if `_x` is the name of a class.

Answer (score 1):

The "duplicate symbol" message means that you're declaring some name (in this case, `_x`) twice in the same scope. Say you had code like this:

```
int _x = 1;
int _x = 2;
```

You'd expect to get an error then, right? You can use the same name for two things at the same time.

The error you're getting is essentially the same. You're declaring `_x` somewhere, and from the compiler's point of view you're doing it twice. There are a few ways to deal with this, depending on what `_x` represents.

chrahey's answer explains about forward class declarations. I won't cover that again here except to say that a forward declaration helps you resolve circular references, where the definition of class A depends on class B and vice versa.

If `_x` is a variable, it's likely that you're trying to declare it in a header file. The compiler basically copies the contents of each header file that you import into the source file, so if you declare a variable in a header file and then import that header into two or more implementation files, you'll end up with multiple declarations of that variable. To get around that, use the `extern` keyword to tell the compiler "this name will be declared somewhere else" and then put the real declaration in an implementation file:

Foo.h:

```
extern int _x;
```

Foo.m

```
int _x;
```

Pretty much the same thing goes for functions. It doesn't appear that `_x` is a function, but if it were, and if you were silly enough to put the function definition in a header file, then you'd again get an error if that file were imported into more than one implementation file. This is why header files contain prototypes, not definitions:

Foo.h:

```
int foo(int a);
```

Foo.m

```
int foo(int a)
{
    return a + 10;
}
```